# How to add a Selectbox to Run Toolbar in Intellij with DevKit

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, devkit

I want to add a Selectbox like this to the Run Toolbar in Intellij to select between different Deploymentpaths.

[image]

I was able to add Buttons and Menu Items but i cant figure out how to add a Selectbox.

Can someone give me a hint how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I would just use multiple identical launch configurations with different deploymentpaths. They should automatically list under the other launch configurations everytime you use that specific config for a launch.

Comment: Currently i am doing it like that. A selectbox like in netbeans would be much more comfortable